# XML Do not Deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML file. I wrote a class structure of the file. When I trying to deserialize I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).

I do not know what is wrong with the class structure:

Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Commands>
  <Command Name="ACK" Value="00"></Command>
  <Command Name="Supervise / Poll" Value="01"></Command>
  <Command Name="Sequence number re-sync" Value="02"></Command>
  <Command Name="STATUS" Value="10"></Command>
  <Command Name="REQUEST" Value="20"></Command>
  <Command Name="RESPONSE" Value="30"></Command>
  <Command Name="Validation" Value="33"></Command>
  <Command Name="Stop Request" Value="35"></Command>
  <Command Name="WRITE" Value="40"></Command>
  <Command Name="DATA" Value="50"></Command>
  <Command Name="CONFIG" Value="60"></Command>
  <Command Name="STARTUP" Value="70"></Command>
  <Command Name="Pass-through" Value="80"></Command>
  <Command Name="MULTI COMMAND" Value="90"></Command>
</Commands>
```

Here is the class structure:

```cs
[XmlRoot("Commands")]
public class XMLCommands
{
    [XmlElement("Command")]
    public List<XMLCommand> Command{ get; set; }

    public XMLCommands()
    {
        Command = new List<XMLCommand>();
    }

    public class XMLCommand
    {

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public XMLCommand()
        {
            Name = "";
            Value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method I read the XML with:

```cs
public CoreBusAnalyzing(string PathAnalyze)
    {
        _pathToAnalyze = PathAnalyze;
        _stopAnalyzing = false;
        _XMLModule = new XMLModule();

        //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLModule));

        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("XMLModule.xml");
        //string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //_XMLModule = (XMLModule)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        //reader.Close();

        _XMLCommands = new XMLCommands();


        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLCommands));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("XMLCommand.xml");
        reader.ReadToEnd();
        _XMLCommands = (XMLCommands)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: remove `reader.ReadToEnd();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading your data stream to the end, then passing the stream to the `Deserialize` method - at this point the stream has already been read.

You should remove the `reader.ReadToEnd()` line from your code.